# Sorting names alphabetically, array error

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I want to sort names alphabetically. I've been looking around online for some examples, and I modified some code I found

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void main()
{

    char* str[]{"john", "mike", "alex", "rick", "chris"};
    char* temp[] = {"temp"};

    int i, j, z;

    bool status = true;
    if (status)
    {
        status = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            z = strcmp(str[i], str[i + 1]);
            if (z > 0)
            {
                temp = str[i];
                str[i] = str[i + 1];
                str[i + 1] = temp;
                status = true;
            }


        }




    cout << "Strings (Names) in alphabetical order : \n";
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

On line 24`(temp = str[i])` I'm getting error message:

> char* temp[1] must be modifiable lvalue, and on line 26 '=' is reporting "char temp[1] value of type char** cant be assigned to entity of type char*"

I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: *"I want to sort names alphabetically."* TL;DR - use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort and `std::string`, of course

Comment: This is needed for my class, and i am not allowed to use sort()

Comment: Let me guess... you are not allowed to use `std::string` and `std::vector` or `std::array` either.

Comment: These questions stating "I can't use x" are pointless unless you tell us what you *can* use.  Otherwise we can go on forever with proposed solutions that get rejected because "using x is not allowed".

Comment: We haven't used vectors at all. We had std::string present in some code examples they gave us but it wasn't the main focus, so i really don't know much about it. We use these arrays like in code above 99% of the time. We were asked to write our own sorter without using built in sort(). I found out about strcmp when looking online, i would just like to know why it's giving me that error. I tried to initialize arrays as string instead of char, but then strcmp wouldn't work. It gives me error "no suitable conversion from std::string to char"

Comment: Has there been/should there be a [c++84] tag or [no-std] tag for these `vector`-less questions?

Comment: @ThatNinja I doubt that you're allowed to hand in code you've found.

Comment: Noone asked us to reinvent the wheel. We just need to implement some sort of algorithm. Teacher recommended us to try merge sort but other sorts are allowed as well. And pretty much all examples i found online only sort numbers, not strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some mistakes you are doing in your code you shouldn't like.

Initialise `str[]` as

```
 char* str[] = {"john", "mike", "alex", "rick", "chris"};
```

Otherwise you will get some warning related to `C++` compiler version.

**First for loop should be**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // i < 4 or you'll get sagmentation fault
        {
            z = strcmp(str[i], str[i + 1]);
            if (z > 0)
            {
                temp[0] = str[i];    // temp[0] instead of temp
                str[i] = str[i + 1];
                str[i + 1] = temp[0];
                status = true;      // here also temp[0]
            }
```

And last one, this code will not sort `str[]`. The output of you code(after obove modification) will something like this:

```
Strings (Names) in alphabetical order : 
john
alex
mike
chris
rick
```

This is partially sorted. To fully sort this array you have to use two `nested for loops` same as `bubble sort`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i needed.